# GD adding border to image not working

Tags: php, gd

So I have [PHP class](https://github.com/arnaspecelis/Demo_generator/blob/master/Demo_generator.php) and I'm trying to add white border with spacing around the uploaded image:

```
private function __draw_white_border()
{
    // get source image and dimensions.
    $src = $this->file_data['im'];
    $src_w = imagesx($src);
    $src_h = imagesy($src);
    // create destination image with dimensions increased from $src for borders.
    $dest_w = $src_w + 10;
    $dest_h = $src_h + 10;
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_w, $dest_h);
    // draw white border (no need for black since new images default to that).
    imagerectangle($dest, 1, 1, $dest_w - 2, $dest_h - 2, 0x00ffffff);
    imagerectangle($dest, 0, 0, $dest_w - 1, $dest_h - 1, 0x00ffffff);
    // copy source image into destination image.
    imagecopy($dest, $src, 5, 5, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h);
}
```

this function works good when not in the class but with this class its not working. It seems that this function don't save image or something, I dont know.. It should load image from `$this->file_data['im']` i think and save to the same destination for further actions. Where is the problem here?

Comment: What do you plan to do with `$dest`?

Comment: @Kenney look at the library I added, the generated image will be used for "demo poster" generator. This is the one of the first step where image should take border around itself

Comment: and for better understanding, this picture should be implemented inside later generated image.

Comment: what I meant was for you to discover that `$dest` contains your generated image, but you don't do anything with it, and so it gets discarded.

Comment: yes i saw that the loaded image is for exaple Resource id#54 and the generated one is Recourse id#55. But I have no idea how to merge it or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create 2 images and layer the main image on top of the slightly larger second image. This way the larger image will be seen around the edge of the main image making it look like a border.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

I use this to layer the images correctly. If the destination image is larger lets say 100x100px. The source image is 80x80px. You will add 10 to the x and y of the source image which will place the source image in the center of the 100x100px image. If the 100x100px image is a plain black image it will generate a clean black border

Comment: but this is what I'm doing, aint?

Comment: try to write the image to a file and check what the file looks like. imagejpeg($dest, "path", 90); if the image has a border then you need to do more with $dest

Comment: yes, when I write it witj imagejpeg - it has borders.

Comment: but I save with different name and when I try to save it with same name I will be using before - nothing happens

Comment: Ah ok it looks like it could be 1 of 2 things. 1. You do not have permissions to overwrite the image. 2. The image is being used and cant be overwritten. Try writing $dest to a temp image path. Destroy all the objects used in this method to make sure the original image isnt locked and try to replace the original file with the copy. Check apaches error log to see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting the amended image back anywhere where you can get to it again after this method is run. This code (see last line) puts it back where the original image came from.

```
private function __draw_white_border()
{
    // get source image and dimensions.
    $src = $this->file_data['im'];
    $src_w = imagesx($src);
    $src_h = imagesy($src);
    // create destination image with dimensions increased from $src for borders.
    $dest_w = $src_w + 10;
    $dest_h = $src_h + 10;
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_w, $dest_h);
    // draw white border (no need for black since new images default to that).
    imagerectangle($dest, 1, 1, $dest_w - 2, $dest_h - 2, 0x00ffffff);
    imagerectangle($dest, 0, 0, $dest_w - 1, $dest_h - 1, 0x00ffffff);
    // copy source image into destination image.
    imagecopy($dest, $src, 5, 5, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h);

    $this->file_data['im'] = $dest;
}
```

Comment: tried this before, but not working.. maybe library have some bugs?